# Intraclass Correlation Coefficient value range vs strength of association

Tags: r, correlation, anova, intraclass-correlation

I read on this site that ICC is a good measure of association(effect size) between nominal and interval data..and the significance test suggested was anova...My question is, given the association is statistically significant i.e. p<0.05 ,for what range of values of ICC the association should be considered strong/moderate/weak/negligible?

Also for relation between ordinal and nominal variables both of which are non dichotomous,which is a better measure of effect size and which significance test should be used.Kindly suggest if any package in R provides these features.